# Python Numpy vectorizing along second and third dimension

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I want to vectorize the calculation along the second and third axis, but I cannot find a way to deal with the last for loop:

```py
n = 3000
D = 2000
delta = np.arrange(D * n).reshape(D, n)
M = np.arrange(D * n * n).reshape(D, n, n)
result = np.zeros(D, n)
for i in range(D):
    result[i, :] = np.dot(delta[i, :], M[i, :, :])
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to work right now (aside from the part of it you are asking about). Could you fix it, and provide a not vectorized version of what you want that works, so we can see?

Answer (score 1):

Let's construct a small example (no need to use big sizes like 3000):

```
In [122]: n,D = 3,2                                                             
In [123]: delta = np.arange(D*n).reshape(D,n)    # not arrange                                   
In [124]: M = np.arange(D*n*n).reshape(D,n,n)                                   
In [125]: result = np.zeros(D, n) 
     ...: for i in range(D): 
     ...:     result[i, :] = np.dot(delta[i, :], M[i, :, :]) 
     ...:                                                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-125-413de80d25a5> in <module>
----> 1 result = np.zeros(D, n)
      2 for i in range(D):
      3     result[i, :] = np.dot(delta[i, :], M[i, :, :])
      4 

TypeError: data type not understood
```

Oops, your `np.zeros` call is wrong!

```
In [126]: result = np.zeros((D, n),int) 
     ...: for i in range(D): 
     ...:     result[i, :] = np.dot(delta[i, :], M[i, :, :]) 
     ...:                                                                       
In [127]: result                                                                
Out[127]: 
array([[ 15,  18,  21],
       [150, 162, 174]])
```

`einsum` is a handy way of matching diverse dimensions.  Note how the `i` dimension matches yours.

```
In [128]: np.einsum('ij,ijk->ik',delta, M)                                      
Out[128]: 
array([[ 15,  18,  21],
       [150, 162, 174]])
```

Let's try the `matmul/@` function which is supposed to handle 'batch' dots like yours:

```
In [129]: np.matmul(delta, M)                                                   
Out[129]: 
array([[[ 15,  18,  21],
        [ 42,  54,  66]],

       [[ 42,  45,  48],
        [150, 162, 174]]])
In [130]: _.shape                                                               
Out[130]: (2, 2, 3)
```

Oops, too much.  Let's add a dimension to `delta` to make it (D,1,n).  That way the `D` dimension is consistently the first of 3:

```
In [131]: np.matmul(delta[:,None,:], M)                                         
Out[131]: 
array([[[ 15,  18,  21]],

       [[150, 162, 174]]])
```

Those are the correct values, but the shape is (2,1,3).  We can get rid of that middle dimension with reshape or index or squeeze:

```
In [132]: np.matmul(delta[:,None,:], M).squeeze()                               
Out[132]: 
array([[ 15,  18,  21],
       [150, 162, 174]])
```

Comment: For anyone who doesn't use IPython, note that `_` is shorthand for *"the result of the last thing I did"*.